# What does the command "PWD=/proc/self/cwd another_executable " mean?

Tags: bash, android-source

When building AOSP 9.0.0_r30 source with these commands:

```
$ make clean
$ make showcommands -j8 > ~/BuildAndroid.txt
```

there are commands line like this in ~/BuildAndoird.txt:

```
[ 58% 62374/106553] PWD=/proc/self/cwd prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin/clang++ ........
```

I suppose this is a bash command,but why there is "PWD=/proc/self/cwd" and a space(not ; or &&) before "prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin/clang++"?What does this mean,I don't think it is legal for bash because space means the following text are parameters instead of command.

Another problem is,what is "/proc/self/cwd",is that a standard proc node?

Some experiment:

```
$ VAR=123
$ VAR=456 echo $VAR
 123
$ echo $VAR
 123
```

So this is really legal,but what is the meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try again:

```
VAR=123
VAR=456 echo $VAR
123
```

Ok, but:

```
VAR=456 /bin/sh -c 'echo $VAR'
456
```

### POSIX variable `$PWD`

`$PWD` will point to current directory

```
echo $PWD; ls -l /proc/self/cwd
/home/user
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 0 mar 26 09:18 /proc/self/cwd -> /home/user
```

Doing so will ensure `$PWD` to be set, as android don't require them at all.

Comment: If android don't require them at all,why to set it?

Comment: Because compiler (`clang`) is not based on *Android*, but *POSIX*.

Comment: I found that there are also lines like "/bin/bash -c "PWD=/proc/self/cwd  prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin/clang ...." ,does /bin/bash -c here have any effect?

Comment: This just add a process level. My use of `sh -c` was just there a way of explanation

Answer (score 3):

It executes the command

```
prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/clang-4691093/bin/clang++
```

but when setting up the environment for this command, it sets the environment variable `PWD` to the value `/proc/self/cwd`. Note that this affects only the environment of the `clang++` process, not the environment/variable space of the shell script.

Comment: This is correct but does not explain why someone would change `PWD`. Changing the value of `PWD` does *not* change the working directory. `PWD=/some/dir ls` will print the content of the current directory, not `/some/dir`. Any idea what's behind setting `PWD` to something different than the current working directory?

Comment: @Socowi : True, but I don't know either why someone wants to do it. My best bet is that the user happens to know the called process is (incorrectly) doing a `getenv('PWD')` somewhere, to find the current WD, and if this process had done a change in the working directory, the only alternative indeed is to set PWD to /proc/self/cwd.

Comment: Is that true?Not only "PWD=*** ls" print the content of current directory,but also "VAR=123;VAR=456 echo $VAR;echo $VAR"  print dual 123....

Comment: `var=456; var=123 echo $var` prints `456` since expansion of `$var` happens *before* `echo` is executed. You can try it with `var=456; var=123 bash -c 'echo $var'` (note the single quotes) or `var=456; var=123 declare -p var`.

Comment: @jw_ : You see the effect better by doing a `VAR=4711 printenv VAR`